# Oracle SQL select rows that are not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Assuming I have a table with columns `first_name`, `second_name` and `score`. I want to list all columns and **the number of rows with the same value in score column** for each of them.

If I have to list only score and rows with the same score, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT score, COUNT(*) FROM tab GROUP BY score;
```

In `SELECT` you can't use columns that are not in `GROUP BY` clause. So what should I do if I want to list not only `score`, but also `first_name` and `second_name`?

Comment: Please give an example. Do you want to select all rows the score of which exists more than once in the table? Or do you want to select all rows along with a number indicating how many rows have that score? Or what else?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, second option, I want to select all rows along with a number indicating how many rows have that score

Comment: Then Monika's query should work for you.

Comment: Yes, but Randy's query with `JOIN` instead of comma should also works fine, isn't it?

Comment: it definitely works - stylisitc differences.

Comment: Yes, Randy is showing how this was done many, many years ago, before Oracle featured analytic functions (`COUNT OVER`) or even explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.). He's even using an outer join (a right outer join at that) that is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use analytical functions:

```
SELECT first_name, second_name, score, COUNT(*)  over (partition by score) FROM tab ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.first_name, t.second_name, t.score, sc.score_count
from tab t
, (select score, COUNT(*) score_count FROM tab GROUP BY score ) sc
where t.score = sc.score
```

Comment: You are not really suggesting a comma separated outer join with Oracle's old proprietary syntax, are you? Why outer join at all? This doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: yes - OP tagged Oracle - so this should be valid.  i answered before OP clarification - outer join is likely not required.